# Unexpected synthetic property @transitionMessages found with standalone compoent angular 15

Tags: angular, angular15, angular-standalone-components

I am migrating the angular application to the `standalone component`. Removed the `ngModule` and `app.module.ts` file

**main.ts**

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent,{
  providers:[importProvidersFrom(FalconCoreModule.forRoot(environment)),
             importProvidersFrom(RouterModule.forRoot(routes))]
}).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

**app.component.scss**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  standalone: true,
  imports:[RouterModule,FalconCoreModule]
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

**auto-complete.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-auto-complete',
  templateUrl: './auto-complete.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./auto-complete.component.scss'],
  standalone: true,
  imports:[FalconCoreModule,CodeGeneratorComponent,HighlightModule,CodeButtonComponent]
})
export class AutoCompleteComponent
  extends BaseFormComponent<string>
  implements OnInit {}
```

**Error**

```
core.mjs:9229 ERROR Error: Unexpected synthetic property @transitionMessages found. Please make sure that:
  - Either `BrowserAnimationsModule` or `NoopAnimationsModule` are imported in your application.
  - There is corresponding configuration for the animation named `@transitionMessages` defined in the `animations` field of the `@Component` decorator (see https://angular.io/api/core/Component#animations).
    at checkNoSyntheticProp (vendor.js:138357:11)
    at DefaultDomRenderer2.setProperty (vendor.js:138340:22)
    at elementPropertyInternal (vendor.js:67372:14)
    at Module.ɵɵproperty (vendor.js:70152:5)
    at MatFormField_div_17_Template (vendor.js:112220:61)
    at executeTemplate (vendor.js:66899:5)
    at refreshView (vendor.js:66783:7)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (vendor.js:67903:9)
    at refreshView (vendor.js:66806:5)
    at refreshComponent (vendor.js:67948:7)
```

If I import `BrowserAnimationsModule` to `auto-complete.component.ts`

```
imports:[FalconCoreModule,CodeGeneratorComponent,HighlightModule,CodeButtonComponent,BrowserAnimationsModule]
```

**Exception**

```
 Uncaught (in promise): Error: Providers from the `BrowserModule` have already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor, import the `CommonModule` instead.
Error: Providers from the `BrowserModule` have already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor, import the `CommonModule` instead.
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're missing the providers required for animations:

```
import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';


bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
    providers: [
      provideAnimations()
    ]
 })
```

Comment: Could you clarify what  is file name (and if possible the file directory) where these changes have to be applied?

Comment: @IdurJul Apply these changes to the main.ts file in your project's file directory.

Answer (score 5):

I also faced with the same issue, afler using Angular 15. An error message was:

```
Error: Unexpected synthetic property @transitionMessages found. Please make sure that:
- Either `BrowserAnimationsModule` or `NoopAnimationsModule` are imported in your application.
- There is corresponding configuration for the animation named `@transitionMessages` defined in the `animations` field of the `@Component` decorator (see https://angular.io/api/core/Component#animations).
```

Adding of BrowserAnimationsModule importing given other issues.
To resolve this you need import 'provideAnimations'

```
import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```

And to add the provideAnimations provider to bootstrapApplication function:

```
bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    provideAnimations()
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally it was solved by replacing within `bootstrapApplication(<1st_arg>,{});` where should be `<1st_arg>` => `AppComponent`, instead of `AppModule`

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this error.

After adding:

```
import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```

And:

```
providers: [
  provideAnimations()
]
```

`appConfig.ts`:
[image: appConfig.ts]

After adding `appConfig.ts`:

[image: after adding appConfig.ts]

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting this type of issue please enter following angular command.
your issue will be resolve.

npm install @angular/animations

than execute it