# My angular material form inside the dialogue doesn't show labels and isn't styled properly untill I enter any input

Tags: angular, angular-material

[image: this is how the form looks like after i press submit or any key]

When I open the dialogue, only the phone number, email, name, and location look like they should, while the other two are not properly stylized and the label isn't showing.

Before I added `appearence="outline"` the fields were not stylized at all.

Whenever I click submit or I press a key on the keyboard, the next input loads, then the next.

My ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-edit-candidate',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MatDialogModule, SharedModule, ReactiveFormsModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatSelectModule, MatInputModule],
  templateUrl: './add-edit-candidate.dialogue.html',
  styleUrl: './add-edit-candidate.dialogue.scss'
})
export class AddEditCandidateDialogue{
  onSubmit() {
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
  }    
  
  form = this.formBuilder.group({
    contactDetails: this.formBuilder.group({
      phoneNumber: '',
      email: ''
    }),
    name: '',
    location: '',
    timeZone: '',
    startDate: '',
    preview: ''
  });

  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<AddEditCandidateDialogue>, private store: Store<IAppState>, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

}
```

My HTML:

```
<div>
  <h2 mat-dialog-title>
    Add Candidate
  </h2>

  <mat-dialog-content>
    <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <!-- ContactDetails Form -->
      <div formGroupName="contactDetails">
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>Phone Number</mat-label>
          <input matInput type="number"formControlName="phoneNumber">
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
          <input matInput type="email" formControlName="email">
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>

      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
        <input matInput type="text" formControlName="name">
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Location</mat-label>
        <input matInput type="text" formControlName="location">
      </mat-form-field>



      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Time Zone</mat-label>
        <input matInput type="text" formControlName="timeZone">
      </mat-form-field>

     

      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Start Date</mat-label>
        <input matInput type="date" formControlName="startDate">
      </mat-form-field>

     

      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Preview</mat-label>
        <input matInput type="text" formControlName="preview">
      </mat-form-field>

     

      <button mat-raised-button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </mat-dialog-content>
</div>
```

I removed some fields for testing purposes

Comment: 1.Sometimes the form fields need a little more time to initialize. You can use the ngAfterViewInit lifecycle hook to trigger change detection after view initialization. 

2.Although not the most elegant solution, setting a timeout can sometimes give Angular the time it needs to properly render components.

Comment: Inside ngOnInit I set an interval of 1ms that sets the value of one of the controls in the form. This works but seems really bad

Comment: Has you import the `MatButtonModule`?, generally this "strange behaviour" happens when an error in console or you forgot "something"
`

Comment: @AdrianBiba, try **not** use "magic trick": if some not work, we need know the reason, not add code without know why.

Comment: Can you check if you are getting any error in the console. Also where are you initialising the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution after @nd10 prompted me to check the console.
This was the error I was getting:
Unexpected synthetic property @transitionMessages found. Please make sure that:

- Either `BrowserAnimationsModule` or `NoopAnimationsModule` are imported in your application.

Had to provide animations by adding provideAnimations() in the app.config.ts.

Here's where I found the solution:
[Unexpected synthetic property @transitionMessages found with standalone compoent angular 15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75172766/unexpected-synthetic-property-transitionmessages-found-with-standalone-compoent)